# Implementing an NFA in Python

Tags: python, finite-automata, nfa

I am trying to implement an NFA in python and I have made some progress however I am stuck because I need to use a 3d array and the indices of the array need to correspond to the current state and the current character to be processed. I have to to use integers as indices of the array and I am trying to convert from string data type to int for this. However, I am getting the error: "list indices must be integers, not str" , any help will be much appreciated. Here is the code I've written so far:

```
"""Initialize States"""
q0=0
q1=1
q2=2

i=0

finstate=q2  #final state is q2

array=[[[0],[0,1]],[[2],[2]],[[],[]]]  #3d array for state transitions

def accepts(state, word):
    global i
    if i==len(word):
        return state==finstate  #if last state is final state accept

    char=word[i]
    i+=1
    int(char) #covert char to int

    nextstates=array[state][char]

    for i in range(len(word)):
        if accepts(nextstates, word):  #recursion
            return True
    return False

def main():
    string= "01" #sample input 
    if accepts(q0, string):
        print("accepts")
    else:
        print("rejects")

main()
```

Comment: `int(char)` does not cause `char` to become an int. `int(char)` is an int; `char` is unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

Well assuming the remaining of your code is correct, you should have something like

```
char = word[i]
i += 1
intval = int(char)
nextstates=array[state][intval]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have done as you've said, however now it is giving the following error: "list indices must be integers, not list" I think it sees the intval variable as a list now and doesn't accept